# How can I pass multiple parameters to a parallel operation in Octave?

Tags: parallel-processing, octave

I wrote a function that acts on each combination of columns in an input matrix. It uses multiple for loops and is very slow, so I am trying to parallelize it to use the maximum number of threads on my computer.

I am having difficulty finding the correct syntax to set this up. I'm using the Parallel package in octave, and have tried several ways to set up the calls. Here are two of them, in a simplified form, as well as a non-parallel version that I believe works:

```
function A = parallelExample(M)
pkg load parallel;

# Get total count of columns
ct = columns(M);

# Generate column pairs
I = nchoosek([1:ct],2);
ops = rows(I);
slice = ones(1, ops);
Ic = mat2cell(I, slice, 2);

##  # Non-parallel
##  A = zeros(1, ops);
##  for i = 1:ops
##      A(i) = cmbtest(Ic{i}, M);
##  endfor

# Parallelized call v1
A = parcellfun(nproc, @cmbtest, Ic, {M});

## # Parallelized call v2
## afun = @(x) cmbtest(x, M);
## A = parcellfun(nproc, afun, Ic);

endfunction

# function to apply
function P = cmbtest(indices, matrix)

colset = matrix(:,indices);
product = colset(:,1) .* colset(:,2);
P = sum(product);

endfunction
```

For both of these examples I generate every combination of two columns and convert those pairs into a cell array that the parcellfun function should split up. In the first, I attempt to convert the input matrix M into a 1x1 cell array so it goes to each parallel instance in the same form. I get the error 'C must be a cell array' but this must be internal to the parcellfun function. In the second, I attempt to define an anonymous function that includes the matrix. The error I get here specifies that 'cmbtest' is undefined.

(Naturally, the actual function I'm trying to apply is far more complex than cmbtest here)

Other things I have tried:

- Put M into a global variable so it doesn't need to be passed. Seemed to be impossible to put a global variable in a function file, though I may just be having syntax issues.
- Make cmbtest a nested function so it can access M (parcellfun doesn't support that)

I'm out of ideas at this point and could use help figuring out how to get this to work.

Comment: Your first example worked for me as expected, returning the correct output. Does this example not work on your machine?

Comment: It does not. I am getting "error: mat2cell: mismatch on dimension 1 (1 != 2)" 10 times with no indication of where that error is occurring. My assumption is that means it's happening somewhere inside parcellfun. I tested out a non-parallel version of the example to verify there wasn't an obvious problem in the thrown-together test function which I'm adding to the above description. Did you change any syntax from what was posted above that might make it work?

Comment: It depends. It is not clear from your example exactly how your code is structured or how your ran it. I suspect that maybe your cmbtest function does not reside in its own file, but declared in the same file as a subfunction? If so, this can be problematic, since a parallel worker (which you could think of as a brand new, clean-state octave instance) might not have access to this function. Also, I don't know what M you use to call it with. If I separate parallelExample.m and cmbtest.m into their own file definitions, and run with M = magic(5) as an example, then I get the intended result.

Comment: Also, in theory the parcellfun should give exactly the same result as cellfun for equivalent arguments. If you want to test if your syntax is correct, don't compare it to a for loop, compare it to an equivalent plain `cellfun` call.

Comment: You were correct, cmbtest was in the same file, which I did not realize would be a problem. My example appears to be working now. I'm still having trouble with my main problem, but I think the scope of this question has probably been addressed at this point.

Comment: I managed to find my problem in my actual implementation. Between multithreading and avoiding the slow for loops, I saw a performance improvement of about 23x on my 12-thread computer. @TasosPapastylianou, if you want to write up your suggestions as an answer I can set it as correct - it seems my 'Parallelized call v1' works fine when the function called is in a separate file.

Comment: Sure. Glad it worked out.  :) I would suggest a slight change in the title of the question though, to make it useful for anyone coming here from google. Presumably something like "error: 'function is undefined' when running parcellfun" might be more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments above to an answer.

When performing parallel operations, it is useful to think of each parallel worker that will result as separate and independent octave instances, which need to have appropriate access to all functions and variables they will require in order to do their independent work.

Therefore, do not rely on subfunctions when calling `parcellfun` from a main function, since this might lead to errors if the worker is unable to access the subfunction directly under the hood.

In this case, separating the subfunction into its own file fixed the problem.